# Java: how to repeat a if check task on every 2 mins

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java code for the following
     `Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();`

**Step1:**  check size of message

**Step2:**  if `size > 1`  Then read the message

**Ste3:**   else i.e `size==0`

**Step4:**  thread starts for repeating the same process in each 10mins ,  if message found then Break

How to write the above steps in java?

I tried like,but don know how to write using java

```
 Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
 if(messages.length==1)
 {
     for(Message message:messages) {
         System.out.println("testtt-------  "+message);
         } 
 }
 else
 {

 }
```

Comment: Use a `TimerTask`. You'll need to make sure to synchronize `inbox` correctly if necessary.

Comment: @chrylis can you explain from a example please . Actually i am readin gmail inbox

Comment: Surely you could get more than one message. So the first test should be "if (messages.length>0) .."

Comment: Actually u can Try Quartz als 0

Comment: Why -neg voting for this ques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` with its [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

If you want to stop executing when a message has been found, add a reference to the executor in your runnable, and call `shutdown` on it when done.

Comment: your code is very direct. Though its helpful. Still i could not solve my issue. It will be helpful if you can demonstrate with an example

Comment: Thankyou after 5 days of long hardwork. Now i able to implement your code. I am a beginner learning java